# Reuse rules in different lexer modes

Tags: antlr4, lexer

I'd like to use several lexer modes which share a good portion of the rules.

The "shared" rules also should produce the same tokens.

So far I have to do it this this way:

```
Id : [a-z]+;
// 50 other shared rules...

mode otherMode;

Id_otherMode : [a-z]+ {setType(Id);};
```

Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

```
Id_otherMode : [a-z]+ {setType(Id);};
```

could be written as

```
Id_otherMode :Id -> type(Id);
```

Also for more "niceness" Id can be a fragment

But I guess what you need to hear is: No, you cannot redifine same tokens in different modes. Maybe reorganize the modes...